# kdb: what is a "blocking-asynchronous" request?

Tags: kdb

KX Whitepaper: ["Common design principles for kdb+ gateways"](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/gateway-design/) mentions

> In addition to the standard asynchronous request type we can also make
> use of **blocking-asynchronous requests** where the client sends a request
> asynchronously and blocks until it receives a callback from the
> server.

#### Question: What is a "blocking-asynchronous" request?

1. Why would we use such a request? From the client's perspective, if it sends an async request then blocks, isn't it the same as sending a sync request?
2. Is this referring to Deferred Response? I assume no, because my understanding is `-30!` deals with sync requests from clients. https://code.kx.com/q/kb/deferred-response/
3. If possible, could you also provide an example in q?

Comment: 1.a) async-methods are popular for latency masking via not blocking until a result is completed, 1.b) given [1.a] we sometimes need to enforce such a wait until an async-method is sure to have been completed, there we are happy to introduce a blocking-(otherwise)-async and enjoy a warranted barrier, until the result was completed. 2) No, deferred responses are not the same as blocking-async

Comment: Thank you. Now from a client's perspective, why would I use a blocking-async query when I can just use a sync query? I still don't quite see the difference here.

Comment: Deferred response is different. It was introduced more recently in v3.6 https://code.kx.com/q/releases/ChangesIn3.6/#deferred-response 
The paper you link predates it kdb+ 3.0 (2012.11.12).
In almost all cases developers should replace blocking-async with deferred sync if writing code now.